# Need to convert code from AS2 to AS3

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

```
stop();
speed = 10;
initial_width = 75;
target_width = 450;
sp = rect1._x;
this.createEmptyMovieClip("emptymc", 0);
emptymc.onEnterFrame = function() { 
for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    if (_root.hit.hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, true)) {
        if (_root["rect"+i].hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, true)) {
            new_x = (_root.sp-(75*(i-1)))-rect1._x;
            rect1._x += new_x/speed;
            n_width = target_width-_root["rect"+i]._width;
            _root["rect"+i]._width += n_width/speed;
        } else {
            n_width2 = initial_width-_root["rect"+i]._width;
            _root["rect"+i]._width += n_width2/speed;
        }
    } else {
        new_x = _root.sp-rect1._x;
        rect1._x += new_x/(speed+50);
        n_width2 = initial_width-_root["rect"+i]._width;
        _root["rect"+i]._width += n_width2/(speed-1);
    }
    _root["rect"+(i+1)]._x = _root["rect"+i]._x+_root["rect"+i]._width;
    _root["movie"+i]._x = _root["rect"+i]._x-1;
    }
};
```

Thanks all, I understand ! I try translate to AS3 and it seems like everything is good. There're still some minor bugs, but I will try to find it and sorry for the inconvenience. :(

Again, thank all. :).

Comment: All the information you need to migrate that code should be here. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html. Good luck! Update your question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Dear Jonatan Hedborg !
First, Thanks you very much. But I just started with Flash..and I must submit assignments tomorrow. So, can you translate this code to as3 code for me now? I would really appreciate ! :(

Comment: I'm afraid we're not going to be able to write a program or translate code for you...just a function or so here and there, when you're stuck on something much more specific.  These forums are really just meant to help when there's a much more specific issue at play.  Sorry, man, you need to make a serious attempt to do it on your own first and just let us know if you have issues.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Thanks bro, I understand ! I try translate to AS3 and it seems like everything is good. There're still some minor bugs, but I will try to find it. Again, thank bro. :)

Answer (score 1):

My code is imcomplete, but can help you.
You need put movie clips called "rect" in array called "rects" and movie clips called movie in array called movies.

Variables and movie clips with prefix "_root" must be declared as global.

```
stop();
speed = 10;
initial_width = 75;
target_width = 450;
sp = rect1._x;

emptymc = new MovieClip();
emptymc.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame (e:Event):void{

    for (var i:int=1; i<=6; i++) {
        if (hit.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY,true)) {

            if (rect.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, true)) {
                new_x = (sp-(75*(i-1)))-rect1._x;
                rect1.x += new_x/speed;
                n_width = target_width-rects[i].width;
                rects[i]._width += n_width/speed;
            } else {
                n_width2 = initial_width-rects[i].width;
                rects[i].width += n_width2/speed;
            }

        } else {

            new_x =sp-rect1.x;
            rect1._x += new_x/(speed+50);
            n_width2 = initial_width-rects[i].width;
            rects[i].width += n_width2/(speed-1);
        }

        rects[(i+1)].x = rects[i].x+rects[i].width;
        movies[i].x = rects[i].x-1;
    }

}
```